# $\int_0^\infty xP_1(x)dx \leq \int_0^\infty xP_2(x)dx$ if $P_2$ has larger standard deviation than $P_1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ be two probability density functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with the same mean
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xP_1(x)dx = \mu = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xP_2(x)dx
\end{equation}
but $P_2$ has a larger standard deviation compared to $P_1$:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x-\mu)^2P_1(x)dx} < \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x-\mu)^2P_2(x)dx}.
\end{equation}
Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty xP_1(x)dx \leq \int_0^\infty xP_2(x)dx ?
\end{equation}
I feel like this should be true (intuitively) but I don't really know how to prove it.

Comment: What are $P_{12}?$ density functions? CDFs?

Comment: A lot of confusion here

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample: Let $P_1(x) = \boldsymbol{1}_{-1/2\ <\ x\ <\ 1/2}$, which is the distribution for $U(-1/2, 1/2)$, and $P_2(x) = \frac{1}{0.3\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left( \frac{x}{0.3} \right)^2 \right)$, the distribution for $N\left(0, 0.3^2\right)$. Both have the same mean of $0$, but different standard deviations: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \approx 0.289$ for $P_1$, $0.3$ for $P_2$, so the preconditions are satisfied.

The proposed inequality is then not true since $$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}xP_1(x)dx =\frac{1}{8} &= 0.125 \\ \int_0^{\infty}xP_2(x)dx =\frac{0.3}{\sqrt{2\pi}} &\approx 0.120\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, this is false. Imagine that the two distributions are supported on $[0, \infty)$ (as many distributions are). Then you are saying that if they have the same mean then they have the same variance, which is a little optimistic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see your point. Strict inequality wouldn't make sense in that case. What if I replace $<$ with $\leq$ everywhere? By the way, I'm not saying same mean implies same variance, I'm asking if the mean are the same but the second variance is larger than the first do we have $\int_0^\infty xP_1dx \leq \int_0^\infty xP_2dx$? In your answer, we would have $\int_0^\infty xP_1dx = \mu = \int_0^\infty xP_2dx$.